# window.open returns null in firefox android version

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, mobile, window.open

i am using `window.open` for my webapp. my problem is that the mobile version of firefox behaves differently from the desktop version.

the problem is in mobile version, `windows.open` returns null even when the pop up is successfully opened.

i have already tested this in other android phones as well, and it also happens there so im sure this is not a configuration issue.

please see below for my code:

```
this.windowRef = await window.open(url, '_blank', strWindowsFeatures);
console.log(this.windowRef); //returns null
```

```
strWindowsFeatures = "popup=yes,width=600,height=700,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,status=no,location=no,addressbar=no"
```

Comment: upon observing, i noticed that this only happens with target = '_blank'